# Binding an appsettings.json section to a list of POCO

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, configuration, poco

Given these two classes

```
public class SerilogSubLoggerConfigurations
{
    public List<SerilogSubLoggerConfiguration> SerilogConfigurations { get; set; }
}

public class SerilogSubLoggerConfiguration
{
    private string _pathFormat;

    public LogEventLevel Level { get; set; }

    public string PathFormat
    {
        get => _pathFormat;
        set => _pathFormat = value.Replace("%APPLICATION_NAME%", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPLICATION_NAME"));
    }
}
```

and an apssettings.json section that looks like this

```
 "Serilog": {
    "SubLogger": [
  {
    "Level": "Information",
    "pathFormat": "C:/Logs/Serilog/%APPLICATION_NAME%/Information/log-{Date}.log"
  },
  {
    "Level": "Warning",
    "pathFormat": "C:/Logs/Serilog/%APPLICATION_NAME%/Warning/log-{Date}.log"
  },
  {
    "Level": "Critical",
    "pathFormat": "C:/Logs/Serilog/%APPLICATION_NAME%/Critical/log-{Date}.log"
  }
],
 }
```

I want to bind the `SubLogger` section to the `SerilogSubLoggerConfigurations` class. I cannot seem to figure out how to get this configuration to create that class with the three items (of type `SerilogSubLoggerConfiguration`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Json config, array of your sublogger objects is called `SubLogger` but in configuration POCO `SerilogSubLoggerConfigurations` it's called `SerilogConfigurations`.
That's why configuration binder could not match them.

In ASP.NET Core there is no possibility (at least for this moment) to change the name of mapped properties, they should match the names of configuration sections. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45856577/5740031) for details.

So you should just rename either POCO property or JSON section name. In your case `SubLoggers` seems to be the most appropriate name:

```
public class SerilogSubLoggerConfigurations
{
    public List<SerilogSubLoggerConfiguration> SubLoggers { get; set; }
}

{
  "Serilog": {
    "SubLoggers": [
      {
        "Level": "Information",
        "pathFormat": "C:/Logs/Serilog/%APPLICATION_NAME%/Information/log-{Date}.log"
      },
      {
        "Level": "Warning",
        "pathFormat": "C:/Logs/Serilog/%APPLICATION_NAME%/Warning/log-{Date}.log"
      },
      {
        "Level": "Critical",
        "pathFormat": "C:/Logs/Serilog/%APPLICATION_NAME%/Critical/log-{Date}.log"
      }
    ]
  }
}

IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json");
IConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
SerilogSubLoggerConfigurations subLoggerConfigurations = configuration.GetSection("Serilog").Get<SerilogSubLoggerConfigurations>();
```

One more note. `Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel` enum does not have a `Critical` level, it has `Error` and `Fatal`.
That's why this item

```
{
  "Level": "Critical",
  "pathFormat": "C:/Logs/Serilog/%APPLICATION_NAME%/Critical/log-{Date}.log"
}
```

will not be loaded correctly. You should change it to:

```
{
  "Level": "Error",
  "pathFormat": "C:/Logs/Serilog/%APPLICATION_NAME%/Error/log-{Date}.log"
}
```