# How can i get all section values immediately to my class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I used to get values of my configuration like this:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration Configuration)
  {
   GraphDBL.Config.Uri = Configuration.GetSection("neo4j:host").Value;
   GraphDBL.Config.UserName = Configuration.GetSection("neo4j:user_name").Value;
   GraphDBL.Config.Password = Configuration.GetSection("neo4j:password").Value;
  }
```

my Config class `

```
public class Config
{
    public static string Uri { get; set; }
    public static string UserName { get; set; }
    public static string Password { get; set; }
}
```

How can i get the result of this in one process? not in turn?

Comment: I guess you can use `Value` property of `IConfigurationSection` instead of `GetValue()
`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationsection.value?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfigurationSection_Value

Comment: how can i pass "host" to it?

Comment: You can use GetValue() like described in the section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.getvalue?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: thanks for help sir!

Answer (score 0):

If you examine `IConfigurationSection`, you will see it has a `Value` property that you can use to get the value.

You have to specify the full path as a paramter to `GetSection`, using a colon like this:

`GetSection("neo4j:host").Value`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` package to be able to use `GetValue` extension method.

To map section to a class you need to have properties with same names as configuration

```
public class Conf
{
    public string Host { get; set; }

    public string User_Name { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And get configuration like this

```
GraphDBL.Config = Configuration.GetSection("neo4j").Get<Config>();
```

Or if you don't want change properties names you can use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54607296/7775908)

```
public class Config
{
    private string host { get; set; }
    private string user_name { get; set; }

    public string Uri
    {
        get
        {
            return host;
        }
        set
        {
            host = value;
        }
    }


    public string UserName
    {
        get { return user_name; }
        set
        {
            user_name = value;
        }
    }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And get config

```
GraphDBL.Config = Configuration.GetSection("neo4j").Get<Config>(options => options.BindNonPublicProperties = true);
```

Comment: Thank you for information about solving the last question sir!

Comment: sir i have added my config class, adding ``GraphDBL.Config = Configuration.GetSection("neo4j").Get<Config>(options => options.BindNonPublicProperties = true)`` this to throws error ``'Config' is a type but is ued like a variable``

Comment: @Artur_Kamalyan `Config` must be non-static class

Comment: sir it doesn't change anything, i removed static, but nothing changed, still same issue

Comment: @Artur_Kamalyan `var config = config.Get<Config>()` will work fine. What is `GraphDBL.Config`? Could you share code of `GraphDBL` class?

Comment: GraphDBL is a library sir, that contains Config class