# Parse json file with different property name than model variable name

Tags: c#, json

This is my `config.json` file:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "min_value": 5,
  }
}
```

which corresponds to this model file:

```cs
public class Settings
{
    public int min_value { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I load this in my Console application

```cs
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: false);

IConfiguration config = builder.Build();
var settings = config.GetSection("settings").Get<Settings>();
```

Everything works! What I want to do is change `Settings.min_value` property to `Settings.MinValue`, but without changing json file. I did this:

```cs
public class Settings
{
    [JsonPropertyName("min_value")]
    public int MinValue { get; set; }
}
```

But not, `MinValue` is parsed to `0` instead `5`. Seems like parsing gone wrong. Where is the problem?

Comment: There is `ConfigurationKeyNameAttribute`

Comment: `config.GetSection("settings").Get<Settings>();` isn't a direct deserialization to Settings from JSON file.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67164103/3181933) from the question I marked yours a duplicate of should solve your problem, as mentioned by Selvin.

Comment: @PoulBak oh no, it should be `int`, not string. I corrected my post.